# Highlight the clicked polygon using R Shiny leaflet in R flexdashboard using map_shape_click

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard (**.rmd** file) in which it has a map (a polygon map). The data source of the map was a ArcGIS shapefile. I was able to make Choropleths based on the map using **Shiny leaflet**. Besides that, I also would like to highlight one polygon (highlight the board of the polygon) each time when I click one in the map. Besides, a bar chart showing the distribution of the data of the clicked polygon will be shown on the right side of the dashboard. However, I couldn't make the polygon highlighted. The polygon wasn't highlighted when I clicked usinf the **input$map_shape_click** in shiny leaflet. Please see the **R** code below.

````
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(leaflet) 
library(shiny)

CNT <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand("./ABC_Polygon"),layer="CNT10_ABM", GDAL1_integer64_policy = TRUE)
df_travel <- read.csv("./CNT_trip.csv")
CNT_Trip <- df_travel %>% 
        group_by(origcnt) %>%
        summarise(cnttrips=n())
cnt_mdata <- merge(CNT,CNT_Trip, by.x="CNT10", by.y="origcnt")

TAZ Level Travel
======================================================================

Column {data-width=650}
---------------------------------------------------------------------
### County trip map 

```{r}  

bins <- c(0, 50, 100, 300, 600, 1000, 2000, 5000, Inf)
pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = cnt_mdata$cnttrips, bins = bins)

renderLeaflet({
 map  <- leaflet(cnt_mdata)%>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")%>%
    addPolygons(
            fillColor = ~pal(cnttrips),
            weight=0.1,
            opacity = 1,
            fillOpacity = 0.7,
            layerId = cnt_mdata$CNT10)%>%
      addLegend(position = 'bottomright', pal = pal, 
            values = cnt_mdata$cnttrips, title = 'Number of Trips')

 })

click_cnt <- eventReactive(input$map_shape_click, {

        x <- input$map_shape_click
        y <- x$id
        return(y)

 })


 observe({

  req(click_cnt()) # do this if click_cnt() is not null

  # Add the clicked cnt to the map in aqua, and remove when a new one 
  # is clicked
   map <- leafletProxy('map') %>%
      removeShape('selected') %>%
      addPolygons(data = cnt_mdata[cnt_mdata$CNT10 == click_cnt(), ], 
                  fillcolor = FALSE,
                  color = '#00FFFF', opacity = 1, layerId = 'selected')

    })

  # taz_data <- reactive({
  #   
  #     # Fetch data for the clicked tract
  #     return(df_travel[df_travel$origcnt == click_cnt(), ])
  # 
  #   })


  leafletOutput('map')  

```
````

The **CNT10** is the numeric indicator of polygon in data **cnt_mdata** and **CNT** file. The **origcnt** is also the numerica indicator of polygon in data file **CNT_Trip** and **df_travel**. I ran the above code chunk in console, and no errors and warnings were shown. However, when I ran the **.rmd** file by clicking the Run Document in RStudio, it did show the choropleth map. but when I clicked the polygon, nothing came up. I couldn't find out what's wrong with my code.